How do I make a program ignore the lack of a variable?
I am currently working on a problem where I am trying to to turn a full name "First Middle Last" into their Last Name, X.Y. X representing their first initial and Y representing their  middle initial.
full_name = input()
full_name2 = full_name.split(' ')
first_name = full_name2[0]
middle_name = full_name2[1]
last_name = full_name2[2]
first_name2 = list(first_name)
middle_name2 = list(middle_name)
first_inital = first_name2[0]
middle_inital = middle_name2[0]
print(last_name + ', ' + first_inital, '.' + middle_inital, + '.')

This code works but I am also trying to make it where if the input lacks a middle name, it still outputs.
I.e. if the input is "James Paul McCartney" the output is "McCartney, J.P" but if the input is "Paul McCartney" The output is "McCartney, P."
I've tried adding another variable full_name3 = ''.join(last_name + ', ' + first_inital, '.' + middle_inital, + '.')
I've tried the code I posted above. Honestly, that is really it, I am super beginner level, and those are the only two avenues I know of.

"if the input is..."—Did you try an if statement?

You don't need to create lists; str values are indexable. first_initial = first_name[0] will work fine, for example.

you also don't need to unpack every name separately. (first, middle, last) = full_name.split(" ") works fine. Just remember to validate your input because there is nothing that verifies you got three strings separated by a single space right now.

How do you know which part of the name is missing e.g. 'James Paul'?

Falsehoods programmers believe about names

Your question is misdirected. You generally want to make variables predictably exist. A better approach is probably to use a simple iteration over the non-final tokens:
full_name = input()
names = full_name.split(' ')
initials = [name[0] for name in names[:-1]]
print(f"{names[-1]}, {".".join(initials)}.")

You can decompose the problem further into smaller steps if you like; for example, you could add last_name = names[-1]; but as you get more familiar with the language, it becomes increasingly obvious that names[-1] is the last element of names. Similarly, you might put punctuated_initials = ".".join(initials) + ".". On the other hand, my reaction to your attempt is that maybe there is such a thing as too many variables, especially if you only have numbers in their names to tell them apart. (Typing fatigue seems to have set in by the time you needed to spell initial!)
Another nice embellishment might be last_name = names.pop() and then you can loop over the entire list of remaining names without slicing with [:-1].
Tangentially, perhaps notice how Python uses subscripts to access individual elements of both lists and strings. It is convenient and succinct that you can use thing[0] to get the first character when thing is a string, and the first element when thing is a list; but also sometimes confusing (we all end up wasting time on bugs where we loop over the characters of a string when we meant to iterate over the strings in a list; though type hints help a lot for avoiding that particular error.)
Perhaps this is a good time to mention Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names. Quixotic cases aside, some "middle names" are family names which should be spelled out in full.

Examples include Barbara Bel Geddes, Gabriel Garcia Marquez, Werner von Braun, etc etc.

Don't get me wrong, I agree with you completely. Alas, this is for school and is graded by an a.i. So it really isn't up to me. The whole reason I am asking here is I tried reaching out to my professor and got the silent treatment.

@GriffinsTale just remember that like real world math calculations are much messier than the story problems in textbooks, real world programming tasks (even the same task like storing user names) have many many more considerations than the constraints of a problem given to beginners.

@JaredSmith, I genuinely appreciate the wisdom, and I will keep that in mind.

Take index -1 to get the last one, no matter the size, then you can directly access a letter of a string, don't need a list
full_name = input().split(' ')

output = full_name[-1] + ", " + full_name[0][0] + "."

if len(full_name) == 3:
    output += full_name[1][0]

print(output)


The worked! The only edit I had to make was changing the if-statement's output line to 'output += full_name[1][0] + "." Thank you so much!
